# How to lock a group of rows with 'SELECT FOR UPDATE'

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 'jobs' table with a tasks that needs to be processed.

A simple query like  `SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE status='new' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` can be used by a set of workers to process rows in parallel one by one.

But what I need is to lock all rows linked to the single person by single worker.

Something like this would do the job `SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE status='new' GROUP BY person_id LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` but locking does not work with aggregate functions.

In case of using subquery `SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE person_id in (SELECT person_id FROM jobs WHERE status='new' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` I have no guaranty all rows would be locked by same thread.

Locking a 'person' row in 'persons' table instead of job is not a preferable solution as this table is used by other processes as well.

Please advice if there is a simple way to do this.

Comment: Why are you wanting to explicitly lock rows in the first place? I think there is a better alternative if you can share a wider problem statement. Also, an RDBMS is not really the best tool to use to build a job queue - have you considered using a dedicated MQ server such as RabbitMQ, Kafka, or SQS?

Comment: This design smells a bit 'funny'. The fact you want to lock rows like this suggests you might have an XY problem.

Comment: "I [would] have no guaranty all rows would be locked by same thread."  You don't anyway.  What if a new job belonging to an already-locked person were to be inserted after the existing ones for that person were locked?

Comment: You are right, the case I have used to illustrate a problem here is a bit artificial... But never the less, I'm only looking for advice if it's possible to write a PostgreSQL query which would lock and return all records related to first available 'person' in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) in order to exclusively lock a "person" entity.

Comment: That would work, but I'll need to query every person form every worker, which is a lot of extra request. I was hoping for some elegant solution where I can take and lock records form db with single query.

Comment: @AndrewRozdolsky you could combine a call to `pg_try_advisory_lock` with your main query. If the result to the function call is `true` then it means that the worker is good to go.

Comment: Bingo, ```SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE status='new' AND pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(pic.person_id) = true LIMIT 1``` seems to do just what I need. I will also add GROUP BY to eliminate repeated attempts to acquire lock on same id.

Comment: @AndrewRozdolsky If you're going to use advisory locks anywhere else in the same instance, remember that it's up to you to avoid collisions between different modules trying to lock different resources that happen to have the same id.